# BouncyCastle Rijndael 256 Implementation

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I modified the implementation from this [website](http://svn.debux.org/webmotion/trunk/webmotion-server/src/test/java/org/debux/webmotion/server/BouncyCastleTest.java) to include a salt:

```
package de.xxx.yyy.main;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA3Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RijndaelEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS12ParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.junit.Test;

public class test {

    private char[] password = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    private byte[] salt = "0123456789".getBytes();
    private int iterationCount = 5;

    @Test
    public void testEncryptRijndael() throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {

        PKCS12ParametersGenerator pGen = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA3Digest(256));
        char[] passwordChars = password;

        final byte[] pkcs12PasswordBytes = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passwordChars);
        pGen.init(pkcs12PasswordBytes, salt , iterationCount );     

        BlockCipher engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
        CBCBlockCipher cbc = new CBCBlockCipher(engine);
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbc, new PKCS7Padding());

        ParametersWithIV aesCBCParams = (ParametersWithIV) pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 256);
        cipher.init(true, aesCBCParams);

        byte[] input = "Hallo ich bin ein Test".getBytes();
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

        int cipherLength = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        cipher.doFinal(cipherText, cipherLength);

        String result = new String(Base64.encode(cipherText));
        System.out.println("testEncryptRijndael result : " + result);
        assertEquals("cMoMSNMNsikAkLjaheE6iD48Xkfvo7Y6gS8/zroGfHc=",result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDecryptRijndael() throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {
        PKCS12ParametersGenerator pGen = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA3Digest(256));
        char[] passwordChars = password;

        final byte[] pkcs12PasswordBytes = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passwordChars);
        pGen.init(pkcs12PasswordBytes, salt , iterationCount );     

        BlockCipher engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
        CBCBlockCipher cbc = new CBCBlockCipher(engine);
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbc, new PKCS7Padding());

        ParametersWithIV aesCBCParams = (ParametersWithIV) pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 256);
        cipher.init(false, aesCBCParams);

        byte[] output = Base64.decode("cMoMSNMNsikAkLjaheE6iD48Xkfvo7Y6gS8/zroGfHc=".getBytes());
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(output.length)];

        int cipherLength = cipher.processBytes(output, 0, output.length, cipherText, 0);
        int outputLength = cipher.doFinal(cipherText, cipherLength);
        outputLength += cipherLength;

        byte[] resultBytes = cipherText;
        if (outputLength != output.length) {
            resultBytes = new byte[outputLength];
            System.arraycopy(
                    cipherText, 0,
                    resultBytes, 0,
                    outputLength
                    );
        }

        String result = new String(resultBytes);
        System.out.println("testDecryptRijndael result : " + result);
        assertEquals("Hallo ich bin ein Test", result);
    }
}
```

Is this a good implementation, or are there some mistakes, logical errors or security risks?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using Rijndael-256. It's generally considered less secure than the much more heavily scrutinized AES (which is based on Rijndael-128). If you want to do AES-256, you use the Rijndael-128 cipher, with a 256 bit key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you used a more interesting test string instead of `"value"` and that in `testEncryptRijndael` you replaced `assertNotNull` with a more strict `assertEquals`.

Since your tests are different from the originals, it would be better to rename them to `testEncryptRijndaelWithSalt` and `testDecryptRijndaelWithSalt`, respectively. And keep the originals too.

In both the original tests and yours I don't see the point of the logging and printing statements. I think you can drop that. They do no harm, but they might invite the bad habit of *reading* test outputs instead of focusing on adding proper assertions.

There's a lot of duplication in the encryption and decryption cases. Perhaps you could move that logic to a common private helper method. That can reduce possible typing errors.

I don't see the point of this `if` block:

> ```
>  if (outputLength != output.length) {
>      // ...
>  }
> ```

The thing is, in a unit test everything should be predictable: you should already know at this point the outcome of that condition. If `outputLength` should be equal to `output.length`, then drop the `if` but keep the block of code. Otherwise delete the whole thing. You can add an assertion for the condition as a sanity check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A private helper method is a good idea. I will do that. The if-block is there, because I want to generate random Strings, encrypt end decrypt them. So it's there, just for ongoing modifications.